# Ping results in notepad

Tags: cmd, ping

Can anyone please tell what is wrong in this code, what I am trying is to capture the date and time of link fail else, it shall report Link is working or it would be better if it shows the ping response.

```
@echo off
echo Internet Testing by RN Choudhury.
:loop
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 -w 60 > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo %date% - %time% Not connected >> InternetFail.txt else 
echo Link is working
ping -n 30 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` syntax is flawed:

```
if errorlevel 1 (echo %date% - %time% Not connected >> InternetFail.txt) else echo Link is working
```

or for better readabilty:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo %date% - %time% Not connected >> InternetFail.txt
) else (
  echo Link is working
)
```

Note: `ping` may give false positives (`Reply from <localhost>: destination not reachable` technically *is* a response, so `errorlevel` will be zero.

Better use:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 -w 60 | find "TTL=" > nul
```

**Edit** for additional requirements in comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "logfile=InternetFail.txt"
set "host=8.8.8.8"
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -w 60 %host% ^|findstr /r "TTL= \.$"') do (
  echo %%a|find "TTL=" >nul && (
    >>"%logfile%" echo %date% %time% Link is up:   %%a
    echo %date% %time% Link is up:   %%a
  ) || (
    >>"%logfile%" echo %date% %time% Link is up:   %%a
    echo %date% %time% Link is up:   %%a
  )
)
timeout 30 >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: Thanks . It is working fine. But as I mentioned, i want to display the result in the command prompt window and also want to capture them in notepad file. Now the details are being captured in notepad file but they are not displayed in command prompt.  Also in my previous batch file I was able to set a time limit by pinging to the local host, now in this batch file, how can i set a time limit. If i want to test the internet once a minute or in 30 seconds like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Better now?  If the script should run on XP  or lower, replace the `timeout` command with your `ping` workaround (`timeout` was not available in XP).

Answer (score 0):

Continually output internet connection status to text file and host.

Windows 10 64-bit.  Does not require admin privileges.

CMD batch script to continually output internet connection status to text file and host using ping, if/else, echo, re-direction and goto loop.

Ctrl+C to break out of loop.

```
@title Output internet connection status to text file and host.
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. Does not require admin privileges.
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions 
cd.> InternetFail.txt 
:loop
SET errorlevel=
ping -n 2 8.8.8.8 -w 60 | find "TTL=" > nul
REM ping -n 30 8.8.8.8 -w 60 | find "TTL=" > nul
if errorlevel == 1 (
(
ECHO. 
ECHO  %date% - %time% INTERNET DOWN
ping -n 2 8.8.8.8 -w 60
REM ping -n 30 8.8.8.8 -w 60
)>> InternetFail.txt 
ECHO. 
ECHO    Ctrl+C to break out of loop. 
ECHO.
ECHO  %date% - %time% INTERNET DOWN
ping -n 2 8.8.8.8 -w 60
REM ping -n 30 8.8.8.8 -w 60
) else (
ECHO. 
ECHO    Ctrl+C to break out of loop. 
ECHO.  
ECHO %date% - %time%  Link is working.
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1
REM ping -n 30 127.0.0.1
)
goto :loop
exit /b
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the 01st one is the type I want, but i want to only capture the failure times and if possible (failure reasons also) and when link is  there, I want to display the same in the batch file screen.  like


Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=55

Comment: @rab update.  If this answer is useful you should upvote it.